# PHP natsort ignoring optional prefix

Tags: php, natural-sort

Here a sample code:

```
<?php
$temp_files = array("_temp15.txt","temp10.txt", "temp1.txt","temp22.txt","_temp2.txt");

natsort($temp_files);
print_r($temp_files);
?>
```

Actual output:

```
[4] => _temp2.txt 
[0] => _temp15.txt 
[2] => temp1.txt 
[1] => temp10.txt 
[3] => temp22.txt
```

Desired output:

```
[2] => temp1.txt 
[4] => _temp2.txt 
[1] => temp10.txt 
[0] => _temp15.txt 
[3] => temp22.txt
```

In other words, I want to execute a natural sort ignoring a given (but optional) prefix. In this case the optional prefix is `_`.

In my use-case scenario the filenames are unique, regardless if the prefix is present or not. I.e. `temp1.txt` and `_temp1.txt` are NOT allowed.

The ugly solution I found is:

1. cycle among all items and store the keys with the prefix
2. remove the prefix from the array
3. sort the array
4. restore the prefix using the keys collected at point 1

Is there something better than this brute force approach?

Comment: please check above modified code.it should work,i think that is what u needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uasort` with a custom comparison callback, that uses `strnatcmp`. Then you can strip off any `_` prefixes, before you pass the two values to compare to strnatcmp.

```
uasort($temp_files, function($a, $b) {
   return strnatcmp(ltrim($a, '_'), ltrim($b, '_')); 
});
```

Edit: Replaced `usort` with `uasort`, to maintain the keys.

Comment: Neither does this. The prefixes are only removed from the two items that are passed into the comparison function, it does not change anything in the original array.

Comment: Sorry, you're right!